# Is there a way to check that multiple lists are not equal to each other in Python?

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a list of values with variables, like

```
for a in range(0,2):
    for b in range(0,2):
        for c in range(0,2):
            myList = [a, b, c, 1]
```

Then I want to generate all lists such that the ordered pairs [a,b], [b,c] [c,1] are all distinct.

1. How do I do this?
2. Is there a way to check if they are all not equal at once, instead of doing each "inequality" pairwise?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do a multi-way uniqueness check efficiently is to use a hashable type and put the values into a `set`. If the size of the set is the same as the number of items you added to it, they were all unique:

```
for a in range(0,2):
    for b in range(0,2):
        for c in range(0,2):
            if len(set([(a,b), (b,c), (c,1)])) == 3:
                myList = [a, b, c, 1]
                # do stuff with myList here
```

For only three items though, it's probably faster to just do the three inequality tests. Or, since there are exactly 4 valid `[a,b,c,1]` lists, you can just hard code them:

```
for valid_list in [[0,0,1,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,1,1], [1,1,0,1]]:
    # do stuff with valid_list
```

Comment: Could you write out the code for the example I gave above?

Comment: For the `set` approach? Done!